# Is there a way to call an unimplemented abstract method from a supertype?

Tags: java, runnable

I am using a java library which requires certain objects to be used from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread. I would like to create an interface for a program using this library. So far I have this.

```
public abstract class IProgram implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public void run() {
        start();
    }
    public abstract void start();
}
```

In the main method I would like to run whatever subclass is made. For example, if this was the program:

```
public class MyProgram implements IProgram {
    public void start() {
        //Code to run program here...
    }
}
```

I would like to then run MyProgram and have it run as a runnable. Is this possible? If it is, would I put in the main method of IProgram?

Edit: normally to call a runnable I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RunnableImplementation());

Comment: Have you tried it? Generally once you have code, it is trivial to verify it it is possible.

Comment: Considering that there is nothing in the main method I don't see how it could work.